# Cannot start, stop, enter VE using OpenVZ

Tags: openvz

I'm using Debian Unstable kernel 2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64 (But I don't think it's a problem).
After install and run our VEs for several month, our hard disk is nearly full and we add 3 more hard drives to make new RAID 5 Array, format it as ext4 then mount with location /openvz

I have a VE with ID 112, I desire to change its configuration to make private area from /var/lib/vz/private/112 (1) to /openvz/112 (2)
After syncing all data from (1) to (2), I cannot start VE 112. I revert configuration back to original, but, when I use vzctl status 112:, it shows:

```
# vzctl status 112
VEID 112 exist mounted running
```

and cannot enter the ve:

```
# vzctl enter 112
enter into VE 112 failed
```

cannot stop or restart with error: Operation time out. 
I've tried many ways: try to umount, mount the private area, or use MAKEDEV to make tty or pty, using **vzctl chkpnt 112 --kill** but it does not work.

I dont want to reboot this server, it contains 2 others VEs that are running well without problem. If someone did face with same problem, please let me know your solutions.

Thank you very much,

--hung

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to exec commands within your CT using 'vzctl exec'?

If it is possible try

```
vzctl exec 112 ps aux
```

to check what is running within your CT.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot login to your CT because of missing /dev/pts you may mount it with 'vzctl exec':

```
vzctl exec 112 mount devpts /dev/pts -t devpts
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for my question is: I reformat new partition with ext3 and re-sync data. everything worked as normal :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting the VPS up in verbose mode? You can do this by doing:

```
vzctl --verbose start 112
```